# jqplot x axis extra date range

Tags: jquery, charts, jqplot

I rendered the plot chart for a particular month (feb).But I'm getting an extra date on x axis in last. How to remove this filed. I tried using min,max and number ticks but it won't work.

How to remove last date label.?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. jqplot generates automatically the range in the grid. You could use jquery to remove this entry specifically (the last one).